# Parsing date and time strings containing BST and GMT with NodaTime

Tags: .net, nodatime

This is the first time I have picked up [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) for a long while.

Whilst there are some questions around this area, I just wanted to keep this question focused on parsing strings to some date-time objects using NodaTime.  Thus, I am looking at dealing with strings containing GMT and BST in them respectively.

Curiously, there is some trivia [here](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/userguide/trivia) around BST having two different meanings.  In our legacy Java system, we use BST and GMT in a lot of custom code.

So, I put together some quick and dirty tests to get me started.  The last test case fails.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("2021-03-28 00:00:00 GMT")]
[InlineData("2021-03-28 02:00:00 GMT")]
[InlineData("2021-03-28 02:00:00 BST")]
public void parsing_dates(string dateString)
{
    ZonedDateTimePattern pattern = ZonedDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss z", DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
    
    ParseResult<ZonedDateTime> parseResult = pattern.Parse(dateString);

    if (!parseResult.Success)
    {
        testOutputHelper.WriteLine(parseResult.Exception.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        testOutputHelper.WriteLine(parseResult.Value.ToInstant().ToString());
    }
    
    parseResult.Success.Should().BeTrue();
}
```

The exception with the "2021-03-28 02:00:00 BST" string:

`NodaTime.Text.UnparsableValueException: The specified time zone identifier is not recognized. Value being parsed: '2021-03-28 02:00:00 ^BST'. (^ indicates error position.)`

I have trawled through the docs with some tired eyes and can't seem to find what I am looking for.
https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/userguide/text
https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/userguide/zoneddatetime-patterns

Is there a way to parse GMT and BST to a ZonedDateTime?

Comment: Not knowing NodaTime, you may want to try a culture where you know that BST and GMT are called that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use abbreviations when parsing. They're ambiguous, and generally horrible in various ways. ("GMT" is a special case here - IANA *does* include that as a time zone ID, but I'd still suggest avoiding it.) If you can possibly get your data in a better way, that would be great.

Otherwise, you'll need to tweak your data before asking Noda Time to parse it.

If your data is *always* in the Europe/London time zone, and is just "BST" or "GMT", then you can adjust your input based on that (including the UTC offset for disambiguating) and then parse the tweaked version.

Here's a complete example that does that. Note that I had to adjust your test data, as "2021-03-28 02:00:00 GMT" is invalid. The sample below shows the minute before the March transition, and the instant of the March transition... as well as disambiguation in October.

```cs
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] inputs =
        {
            "2021-03-28 00:00:00 GMT",
            "2021-03-28 00:59:00 GMT",
            "2021-03-28 02:00:00 BST",
            "2021-10-31 01:59:00 BST",
            "2021-10-31 01:59:00 GMT"
        };
        foreach (var input in inputs)
        {
            TweakAndParse(input);
        }
    }

    private static readonly ZonedDateTimePattern pattern =
        ZonedDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture(
            "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z '('o<g>')'",
            DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);

    static void TweakAndParse(string input)
    {
        string tweaked = input.EndsWith("GMT") ? input[..^3] + "Europe/London (+00)"
            : input.EndsWith("BST") ? input[..^3] + "Europe/London (+01)"
            : throw new ArgumentException("Unexpected input");

        ZonedDateTime zdt = pattern.Parse(tweaked).Value;
        Console.WriteLine($"{input} => {zdt.ToInstant()}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2021-03-28 00:00:00 GMT => 2021-03-28T00:00:00Z
2021-03-28 00:59:00 GMT => 2021-03-28T00:59:00Z
2021-03-28 02:00:00 BST => 2021-03-28T01:00:00Z
2021-10-31 01:59:00 BST => 2021-10-31T00:59:00Z
2021-10-31 01:59:00 GMT => 2021-10-31T01:59:00Z
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks Jon.  Thanks for including the October clock changes too.